# AWS amplify routing with angular

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, routes, aws-amplify

I've build and angular 8 app and deployed to AWS amplify by connecting to a branch in my repository. 
Routing works on my localhost and it also works on deployed version. The problem is when I reload the page on some sub-route. 
 [image]  
It looks like amplify routing takes care of that request and ignore my angular routing. Reload only works on root page. 
 
I tried this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html with redirecting /<*> everything to '/' but I had no luck with that.

Where and how can I change the way Amplify handles url paths?

Comment: as a "Plan B", you could try enabling hash routing in Angular with `{useHash: true}` (in your App Module imports: `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })`. This is what I ended up doing with my static sites hosted in S3 buckets

Answer (score 3):

[Please try this solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayahn.png)

I also had the same issue and when I apply "Redirects for Single Page Web Apps (SPA)" method it solved everything

Official Doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html

Comment: Thanks, it works well !

Here is the path in text (instead of image which was a nightmare to copy from, lol) : `</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>`